# Getting error on WiFi driver installation on upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS

Tags: drivers, wireless, software-installation, compiling, gcc

My WiFi worked fine with Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP-ab516tx laptop. Then I updated to 20.04 and my WiFi didn't work. My visible network list was empty. I found the now deleted from Github, rtlwifi_new driver for my rtl8723be [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2449277.html). It installed fine and my WiFi worked again. When I upgraded to 22.04, and tried to install it again to get back my WiFi, I got an error. Here is the output of `make`. How can I fix this error and what is causing it?

```
/home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c: In function ‘_rtl92cu_init_chipN_one_out_ep_priority’:
/home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c:617:9: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  617 |         u16 uninitialized_var(value);
      |         ^~~
/home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c:621:17: error: ‘value’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  621 |                 value = QUEUE_HIGH;
      |                 ^~~~~
/home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c:621:17: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c: In function ‘_rtl92cu_init_chipN_two_out_ep_priority’:
/home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c:643:9: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  643 |         u16 uninitialized_var(valueHi);
      |         ^~~
/home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c:644:9: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  644 |         u16 uninitialized_var(valueLow);
      |         ^~~
/home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c:648:17: error: ‘valueHi’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  648 |                 valueHi = QUEUE_HIGH;
      |                 ^~~~~~~
/home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c:649:17: error: ‘valueLow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  649 |                 valueLow = QUEUE_LOW;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:560: /home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1909: /home/sns/Downloads/rtlwifi_new] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-79-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:85: all] Error 2
```

This is `lspci` output.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
```

Results of `lspci -nnk -d ::0280` :

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Here is the complete output of [make](https://pastebin.com/Z5nTU9uy).

Comment: What GitHub repo are you trying to compile?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new). But this is deleted. Somebody posted a Dropbox link with a copy [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2449277.html). I used this on 20.04 and it worked. But gave me this error on 22.04.

Comment: RTL8723BE should work out of the box with no additional drivers. The only thing that's required is disabling power management. Could you load a recent Ubuntu off a USB stick to see if wi-fi works there?

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -nnk -d ::0280`

Comment: This is the output [here](https://pastebin.com/JYJe994b). I will get back to you about booting from a USB.

Comment: Your wireless device already has a driver in place: rtl8723be. The driver you are trying to build, rtl8192cu is incorrect for your device. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 why isn't the installed driver isn't working? I think the repo has multiple drivers. After `make`, there is `make install` and then `modprobe <my driver code>`. It's all in the [README](https://pastebin.com/QtR97Fxu) file of the repo.

Comment: @RA I booted with USB and it had the same problem. No visible networks.

Comment: @nupro I don't know what's happening here. My device is also `10ec:b723` and works OOTB. It prints `DeviceName: WLAN` though and a slightly different subsystem

Comment: @nupro You could try skipping compiling `rtl8192cu` by removing all lines containing `rtl8192cu` in `Makefile` source file

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `sudo dmesg | grep 8723` or: `rfkill list all`

Comment: @chili555 output of [sudo dmesg | grep 8723](https://pastebin.com/PqNsEcac) and [rfkill list all](https://pastebin.com/nK8wZXYZ)

Comment: We need a full diagnostic report. Please check here:https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: @chili555 [Here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/phjd8xqq6q/) is the full diagnostic report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several items in your wireless info report that are concerning. First, there are two competing and probably needless declarations for module parameters. I suggest that they be removed entirely.

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8723be.conf
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Next, netplan is not set correctly.

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Add these lines:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very specific about spacing and indentation so proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

resolv.conf is not set correctly.

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf  /etc/resolv.conf
```

You have no 8192eu device so let’s remove its declaration:

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Remove the 8192eu line. Save and exit nano as above.

Reboot, disconnect the USB ethernet and see if Network Manager takes over the wireless. In any event, let us see:

```
sudo dmesg | grep rtl
```

**EDIT**: You may need a driver parameter. Please do:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

Is there any improvement? If not try the sequence again with `ant_sel=2`. Tell us which improves the signal strength and we'll wite one file to make it persistant.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't get the list of available network in my area but when I walk over to my router i get a very weak signal of my wifi which don't even connect. Here is output to [sudo dmesg | grep rtl](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/fSVkFfbPK2/).

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: I tried both, but none of them worked. no visible network.

Comment: I suspect, then, that neither antenna wire is firmly snapped into place: https://content.spiceworksstatic.com/service.community/p/post_images/attached_image/d5142330-5419-490c-9fd1-5ca118b215d8-wlan1.jpg

Comment: I only have one antenna. [Front and back](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z5mnad20iisa0u3/AAB1DkILWvHeiARZvekhutBca?dl=0)

Comment: So I switched it to the other one, I got my WiFi back. Thank you for the guidance.